# diferrence between R & android.R class

Tags: android

Can anyone explain from this question; whats the difference of 'R' between

```
R.id.myListView
```

&

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Isn't these 2 'R' the same class?

> * Some people has down voted this question. I need to ask them the reason. If you answered the duplicate question & then down voted me it would have made sense. Neither answered my question nor the duplicate one!!! I mean whats the point of down voting some one without even helping? isn't this site supposed to be for help for programmers!! Weird!! ******

Comment: No, they are in different packages. One is in `android`, the other is in `your.packagename`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`R.layout.*, R.id.*`,in fact any `R.something` without the `android.`- part in front of it refers to some resource in your resources folders, e.g. drawables, strings, layouts, ids of widgets etc. `android.R.*` refers to standard android items that come shipped with your SDK

Answer (score 1):

```
R.id.myListView
```

Your `R.java` file (Generated automatically in project/gen folder)
When your application is compiled, aap generates the R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory. For each type of resource, there is an R subclass (for example, `R.drawable` for all drawable resources) and for each resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example, `R.drawable.icon`). This integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource.

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

For example `android.R.id.text1` (in Java) is an identifier of a `TextView` in the Android framework. You can find it in many layouts from the framework (select_dialog_item, select_dialog_singlechoice, simple_dropdown_item_1line, etc.).

Comment: Thanks dude, made it loud & clear.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`android.R` is a built in set of constants provided as a part of the Android app framework.  The other `R` class is a generated representation of your xml resources.

It is valid Java/Android to have multiple classes with the same name, as long as they are in different packages (which is the case here).

Answer (score 0):

**R.id.MyListview** :- R is a class here it is your package Resource

**android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** :- it is android R/Resource class,and you are trying to use it to get layout id of simple_list_item layout

Answer (score 0):

`R.*` is defined by yours.
`android.R.*` is pre defined.